# Вызов команды из cron

Tags: cron

Пожалуйста, подскажите, какую прописать команду в крон, чтобы он подключался к файлу `system/test.php`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если надо просто добавить задачу в крон, выполните команду

```
crontab -e
```

Туда добавляете данные о расписании запуска команды. К примеру, я хочу запускать скрипт `backup.sh` в 5 часов 0 минут по понедельникам. Тогда я добавлю такую запись:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0    5   *      *     1        /home/backup/backup.sh
```

Где

```
m - минуты 0-59
h - часы 0-23
dom - день месяца 1-31
mon - месяц 1-12
dow - день недели 0-7 (0-Вс, 1-Пн, 2-Вт, 3-Ср, 4-Чт, 5-Пт, 6-Сб, 7-Вс)
```

Все что вам надо сделать - это выбрать время запуска, а `backup.sh` заменить на желаемую команду.

Answer (score 2):

Команду надо записать в таком формате:

```
/usr/bin/php path_to_file/файл_который_ты_хочешь_запустить`
```